# HTTP File Download 500 internal server error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm writing an Android app which does exactly the same as our iPad app for our company. But I have 1 issue while developing on the android. The app downloads a file from a webserver. It will call an URL like:

https://www.somedomain.com/API/Download.aspx?param1=test&param2=test2 etc...

On the iPad this is working perfectly (I use the ASIHTTPRequest class for this). But on Android it is giving me only problems.

As soon as I want to download the file with the android, it downloads a file with a 500 internal server error HTML document instead of the PDF file.

I've checked the URL's, they look exactly the same as on the iPad.

The only thing I can imagine, is that the file which the user downloads is created "on the fly". So it takes some time (10 or 20 sec) to generate the file, and then the file is being downloaded.

On android I do this:

I have a class which extends:

```
extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>
```

In a method, I do this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();       
File file = new File(context.getDir("docs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), FileName);

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
ByteStreams.copy(data, output);
Closeables.closeQuietly(output);
```

But this is giving me a 500 internal server error doc instead of the desired PDF file. What am I missing here? (Sorry, I just started developing for Android so I'm not an expert in this case ;-))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stupid from me, changed it to HTTPGet but no difference...

Comment: What kinds of headers do you need to send?  The Accept header, for example, will make a difference.  Does the server return a 302 redirect to the file?  I suspect it's a difference in the default request parameters for HttpGet vs. ASIHTTPRequest.  Also, does your code work for other URIs?

Comment: I do not need to send specific headers. On the iPad I just call the URL nothing more, nothing less... I tried the code for a simple JPG image, that works but again, then the file is present at the time the URL is called, and the API I call generates the file on the fly...

Comment: I also tried some other way, then I got an exception telling me "FileNotExistsException", thats also why I think the device is too quick with the request

Comment: @BalusC How did you recognized it is a POST request and not a get request ?

Comment: @Francy: OP mistakenly coded that in the initial question. See OP's subsequent "Stupid from me" comment and edit history (click "edited" link below question). I already deleted the currently obsolete comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works now... Stupid thing... I constantly created a new HttpClient so the session was not stored among connections. That is why the server returned a 500 internal server error because the user was not known by the server...

Thanks everyone for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your response status code from the server is the problem means that this should have nothing to do with the Android stuff and only to do with the request you're sending.  I notice, though this might be due to intentional omission, that you're doing a POST request without adding any POST params.  Should this be a GET?  I notice that the endpoint is an ASPX path with GET params in the query string.  Maybe your server is set up to only respond to GET and not POST.  How is this being done in the iOS code?  Is there no differentiation between GET and POST, or is this abstracted from you via the library you're using?

Comment: Changed it to HTTPGet, same issue... Well the iPad works perfectly, with the same URL, so it has something to do with the request from the Android, server is running fine.. But what can it be? I'm not familiar with android HTTP stuff, so maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: If you're targeting Android 2.2+, you can start by using AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance([user agent string]); instead of instantiating a DefaultHttpClient.  That class just wraps some optimized default settings for the HttpClient implementation.  Not sure if that will fix your issue straight away, but it's a start.  I would also check the exact URL as it exists before you send it on both platforms.  Maybe you're missing some URL encoding on the parameters?  Remember, 500 status means that the error is happening on the server...so it must be the request.

Comment: Ok I tried AndroidHttpClient, same result. I checked the URL on both devices, exact the same and the same encoding so that cannot be the problem... I think the problem is that the server needs some time to generate the file before it reacts and the HTTP client in the android isn't going to wait for that...

Comment: If it was a server timeout, you'd get a server timeout exception.  When the server returns a 500 error, that means that an exception happened on the server.  Unless you're using a non standards compliant framework on the server or doing something weird manually to generate that status code, an exception is being thrown on the server.  Are you logging anything on the server?  I promise you the error is happening on the server if you're getting an HTTP 500 status code from any normal web framework, and it has nothing to do with Android not waiting long enough.